# Coloring Glossary Terms

Tags: color, glossaries

Using the glossaries package I am trying to color glossary terms so that they are bold and red. I want this to happen in the main document so students know that they are defined in the glossary.

I am using this in the preamble,

`\renewcommand*{\glstextformat}{\textbf\textcolor{red}}`

To get it bold I used this and it worked fine,

`\renewcommand*{\glstextformat}{\textbf}`

Comment: Did you try `\renewcommand*{\glstextformat}[1]{\textbf{\textcolor{red}{#1}}}` ?

Comment: Thank you that has solved my problem. Cheers